# "Giving a clue" phrase

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Which sentence is correct:

1. It gives you some clues on how to do something.
2. It gives you some clues about how to do something.
3. It gives you some clues how to do something.
4. It gives you some clues on doing something.

All the sentences are mine I just do not know whether they are correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the more usual forms is "Give a clue *to* something" or "Give a clue *as to* something"

The [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clue)  gives these examples under the "More Example Sentences" button of the above definition:

> The book gives the reader plenty of clues *to* solve the mystery

> It gives a clue *as to* how to proceed

> The first clue *to* how the clocks actually work came across the Atlantic in 1971

You also get sentences like "This gives you a clue to solving the problem", "We found a clue to the mystery", "The postcard is from Nice, that gives us a clue as to his location" and so on.

Comment: @Swift I might have stressed out that I want the word "how" to be there. Because the clue should be about how to do something not about doing something. For example you can ski very well but you got a new type of skis that you have never skied on. So the sentence should be not "The book gives the reader plenty of clues to ski properly" but "The book gives the reader plenty of clues how to ski on this type of skis" so would be sentence "The book gives the reader plenty of clues **how** to solve the mystery" still grammatically correct?

Comment: Or perhaps it should be "The book gives the reader plenty of clues **as to how to** solve the mystery"?? But it sounds weird to me - the sequence "to how to" - too many "to-s".

Comment: @azerbajdzan If you look at the second example from MW it reads "_It gives a clue **as to how to** proceed_". That is exactly the form you are rejecting because you think it contains an excess of 'to's. Genuinely it is one of the more common ways in which "give a clue" is used.